# How to initiate a pull-request for an old piece of code in a `git` medium?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, github-codereviews

I have a repository that I have developed over a period of time. It includes a series of files that I would like to get peer-reviewed via Pull-request. One pull-request for each file in this repo will be exactly what I need.

In the past, I have initiated code-reviews for new pieces of code or the suggested changes and modification on the existing code. However, I never been in a situation that I wanted to get all the files that are already in the repository to get reviewed.

One way that I tried was removing files from master branch, and make a pull-request when I try to push them again from another branch (forked/cloned from the origin/master). But, I am not sure if this is the best way to do this.

What is the best way to code-review existing code?

Comment: Your described process (1 file per PR) doesn't seem practical to me. It uses git in a way it has clearly not been designed to, and the "changes" in your "pull requests" don't represent changes at all. But beyond that, how are you supposed to review a *lone* file? Files in a codebase are almost always related to each other and it makes little to no sense to isolate code review in this way. Reviewing *only* the CSS file but not the HTML it applies to? I might miss something in the picture, but I personally don't get the point so far.

Comment: @RomainValeri the reason for file-by-file review is that in this specific repo each file is 100% independent of all others.

Comment: Yes, in this context it could make much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For existing code, as illustrated in "[Recipe: code reviews for existing code with GitHub](https://thib.me/recipe-code-reviews-for-existing-code-with-github)", the PR would include *all* the files, not just one file at a time.

Example: [`thibaudcolas/react-streamfield` PR 1](https://github.com/thibaudcolas/react-streamfield/pull/1).

Once the PR is in place, you can leave comments file by file, as shown in this review [pullrequestreview](https://github.com/thibaudcolas/react-streamfield/pull/1#pullrequestreview-194319442).

See "[Commenting on a pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/commenting-on-a-pull-request#adding-line-comments-to-a-pull-request)"

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/commits/hover-comment-icon.gif]

That can be done for each file individually.

Comment: I do not see this "plus" sign when I roll over my cursor on the lines with no change. I have a snapshot of it. But it seems images cannot be posted in comments.

Comment: I found my cursor can edit *3 lines* above and below the changed area.

Comment: @Rotail the doc mentions "After you open a pull request in a repository, collaborators or team members can comment on the comparison of files between the two specified branches, or leave general comments on the project as a whole." Make sure you have the correct right. And that you are trying on the comparaison view ("Files Changed").